# How to stop File Explorer from using Tabs?

Tags: windows-10

I don't like tabs in explorer because I can't see the folder name. I'd prefer every instance I start of file Explorer to open in its own windows. This does not seem to be affected by the folder options, "Open each folder in its own window," as I would expect. Instead, it's opening a tab in an existing window.

How can I configure Windows 10 file explorer to open a new windows with each instance I start of file explorer (vs a tab within an already open file explorer window)?

Comment: Seems like you have a third-party software that opens them in tabs.

Comment: Screenshots would help others understand your question better.

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful. I do have some software installed that might be interfering. I didn't think of that. Let me test this.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Moshe Gross, I discovered that my multiple monitor software was causing this behavior. As soon as I turned it off, the problem resolved.